# Queue By Using Stack

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have implemented a queue by using a stack data structure. How could I improve it?

```
package _amazonAskedQuestions.dataStructures;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Queue_Stack<T> implements  Iterable<T>{

    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<>();

    public void enqueue(T item){
        Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<Integer>();
        while(!stack.empty()){
            temp.push((Integer) stack.pop());
        }
        stack.push(item);
        while(!temp.empty()){
            stack.push((T) temp.pop());
        }
    }

    public T dequeue(){
        return stack.pop();

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return (Iterator<T>) stack.lastElement();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        Queue_Stack<Integer>  qs = new Queue_Stack<>();

        qs.enqueue(9);
        qs.enqueue(8);
        qs.enqueue(1);
        qs.enqueue(3);
        qs.enqueue(4);
        qs.enqueue(5);

       System.out.println( qs.dequeue());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Queue_Stack` only works with `Integer`.  I tried using `String` and got a `ClassCastException`.

I made some modifications to your code.  I added a test to make sure you don't get an error if you dequeue more than you enqueue.  I used the underlying iterator to get rid of the temp `Stack`.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Queue_Stack<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<>();

    public void enqueue(T item) {
        stack.push(item);
    }

    public Optional<T> dequeue() {
        if (!stack.empty()) {
            T item = stack.iterator().next();
            stack.remove(0);
            return Optional.of(item);
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return (Iterator<T>) stack.iterator();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue_Stack<String> qs = new Queue_Stack<>();

        qs.enqueue("zeta");
        qs.enqueue("alpha");
        qs.enqueue("beta");
        qs.enqueue("gamma");

        Iterator<String> iter = qs.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }

        System.out.println(qs.dequeue());
        System.out.println(qs.dequeue());
        System.out.println(qs.dequeue());
        System.out.println(qs.dequeue());
        System.out.println(qs.dequeue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gilbert Le Blanc's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/241080/203649) already covered all the aspects of your question, I'm adding just one consideration
about the `Stack` class from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

```
A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.
```

So instead of a `Stack` instance `stack` in your code you should consider to use :

```
Deque<T> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
```